# $a(n+1, k) = ka(n,k) + a(n,k-1)$

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

While working a combinatorial problem, I have encountered the recurrence relation $$a(n+1, k) = ka(n,k) + a(n,k-1)$$
where $a(0,0) = 1$ and $a(0,k)=0$ if $k \ne 0$.

Except for the $k$ multiplier, this would be the same recursion as the binomials.

Does anyone know about these numbers? Particularly if there is a non-recurring expression for them?

Some facts I've noted: $$a(0,k) = 0, k>0$$$$a(n,k)=0, n < 0\text{ or }k<0\text{ or } n < k$$
Restricting to $n \ge 1, 1 \le k \le n$

$$a(n,1)= a(n,n) = 1$$ $$a(n,2) = 2^{n-1} - 1$$ $$a(n,n-1) = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$$
and it appears that $p \mid a(p, k), 2 \le k < p$ for prime $p$, though I've not confirmed it.

Comment: The original statement (first three lines) seem to say nothing about $a(n,k)$ for $n>0$.

Comment: Sorry. I absent-mindedly left off the "+1" on the LHS. Corrected now. @almagest

Comment: These are the [Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind#Recurrence_relation).

Comment: @BrianM.Scott - perfect. Thank you.

Comment: @Paul: My pleasure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get this question out of list of unanswered questions, let me post an answer. As Brian M. Scott points out in the comments, this recursively defined sequence is known as Stirling numbers of the second kind.

As a reference, see Section 1.4: Set Partitions of the wonderful book *Combinatorics: The Art of Counting* by Bruce Sagan. A free copy of the book is available from the author's website:

https://users.math.msu.edu/users/bsagan/Books/Aoc/final.pdf

Given a set $T$, Sagan defines $S(T, k)$ to be the set of all set partitions $\rho \vdash T$ with exactly $k$ blocks. Then the Stirling numbers of the second kind are defined by $S(n, k) := \# S([n], k)$ where $[n]=\{1, 2, ..., n\}$.

In particular, Theorem 1.4.2 (in page 11) shows the desired recurrence relation, namely $S(0,0)=1$, $S(0, k)=0$ for $k>0$, and
$$
S(n, k) = k S(n-1, k) + S(n-1, k-1)
$$
for each $n\geq 1$.

Comment: I'll accept it. I no longer remember what I needed them for, now.